# MongoDB query for set difference of collection groups

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, difference

Given a set of `modified` records and an `original` set of records. I want to be able to write a query that will essentially give me the set difference from the `original` "set" to the `modified` "set".

So given two sets, `original` and `modified` like so:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "set": "original", "key" : "foo", "element" : "bar" }
{ "_id" : 2, "set": "original", "key" : "bar", "element" : "old" }
{ "_id" : 3, "set": "original", "key" : "qux", "element" : "abc" } # Deleted

{ "_id" : 4, "set": "modified", "key" : "foo", "element" : "bar" } # Unchanged
{ "_id" : 5, "set": "modified", "key" : "bar", "element" : "new" } # Changed
{ "_id" : 6, "set": "modified", "key" : "baz", "element" : "bar" } # Created
```

I want to get some sort of result from the difference query that either looks like a cursorable set of documents, like:

```
{ "_id" : 3, "deleted": True}
{ "_id" : 5, "changed": True}
{ "_id" : 6, "created": True}
```

Or less ideal (only because it's not as `cursor`-able):

```
{
    "deleted": [3],
    "changed": [5],
    "created": [6]
}
```

I'm not restricted to result formats, but rather just want to figure out how to do this calculation and want to demonstrate what I'm looking for.

I see that Mongo has a [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) feature, but I'm having trouble applying it to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$key",
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
            lastId: { $last: "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            lastId: 1,
            original: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$docs", as: "d", cond: { $eq: [ "$$d.set", "original" ] } } } , 0 ] },
            modified: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$docs", as: "d", cond: { $eq: [ "$$d.set", "modified" ] } } } , 0 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            lastId: 1,
            state: {
                $switch: {
                    branches: [
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$original", undefined ] }, then: "created" },
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$modified", undefined ] }, then: "deleted" },
                        { case: { $ne: [ "$modified.element", "$original.element" ] }, then: "changed" }
                    ],
                    default: "notModified"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$state",
            ids: { $push: "$lastId" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            _id: { $ne: "notModified" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            stats: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$ids" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: "$stats"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Initially you need to use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to get `modified` and `original` fields per  `key`. Then you can use [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/index.html) to determine state based on those two fields. Finally you can `$group` again (by this `state`) and use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) with [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) operators to dynamically get your keys based on detected states. Final result:

```
{ "deleted" : [ 3 ], "changed" : [ 5 ], "created" : [ 6 ] }
```

EDIT: Alternatively you can get single document per key using below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$key",
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
            lastId: { $last: "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            lastId: 1,
            original: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$docs", as: "d", cond: { $eq: [ "$$d.set", "original" ] } } } , 0 ] },
            modified: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$docs", as: "d", cond: { $eq: [ "$$d.set", "modified" ] } } } , 0 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            lastId: 1,
            state: {
                $switch: {
                    branches: [
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$original", undefined ] }, then: "created" },
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$modified", undefined ] }, then: "deleted" },
                        { case: { $ne: [ "$modified.element", "$original.element" ] }, then: "changed" }
                    ],
                    default: "notModified"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            state: { $ne: "notModified" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: "$lastId",
            state: 1
        }
    }
])
```

outputs:

```
{ "state" : "created", "_id" : 6 }
{ "state" : "changed", "_id" : 5 }
{ "state" : "deleted", "_id" : 3 }
```

Comment: Wow! Now, because I'm working with a large dataset, I'd ideally like to have a "cursor"-able result (rather than returning a stupid-large array in my result. How could I do something similar to produce something like my first/ideal result suggestion?

Comment: @Dovmo your first solution is a single document, so do you expect it to be an array instead ?

Comment: @Dovmo but basically you can take just first three pipeline stages to get document per `key` in final result set

Comment: Just fixed the question. Yeah, I meant the result being a collection of documents, not a single document

Comment: There is one limitation here, it's hard to get `{ "_id" : 3, "deleted": True}` but it's easy to get `{ "_id" : 3,  state: "deleted"}`. Is that fine for you ?

Comment: Absolutely. The point in my mind is handling a large dataset, and that solves that problem. If you're going to add that solution, can you keep both solutions in your answer for documentation purposes/for others?

Comment: @Dovmo I've modified my answer but I'm not sure if this will be significantly faster as you need to have this `$group` as a first stage since you need to "pair" input documents. Just try it and you'll see